# Empty exception during GetValues of ODBCDataReader

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, odbc

I seem to have the luck to run into the [funniest problems while deploying my software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780886/net-application-broken-on-one-pc-unhandleable-exception).

Setup:

- Windows 2000 Prof.
- .NET 2.0 Application
- Connection to MySQL 5.0 via ODBCConnection using the MySQL ODBC-Connector 3.51.26

I was deploying my application while I was running into this exception:

```
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetData(Int32 i, SQL_C sqlctype, Int32 cb, Int32& cbActualOut)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.internalGetString(Int32 i)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i, TypeMap typemap)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
at MyAppl.UninterestingStackTace.StartsHere()
```

Yes, that's only the stacktrace...because there is no Exception-Message, there's also no InnerException (I also log those since my last encounter), this is all I got.

The code looks like this:

```
// DtRdr is a passed in ODBCDataReader
if (DtRdr != null && !DtRdr.IsClosed)
{
    Object[] buffer = new Object[DtRdr.FieldCount];

    while (DtRdr.Read())
    {
        DtRdr.GetValues(buffer); // Here happens the exception

        // Modify buffer and use it
    }
}
```

It's only happening on that machine, the fetched data/database is good (verified it via another machine on the same network and I also tested it locally on my dev-machine) and of course it's not reproducible on any other machine.

While looking at it in Reflector, I realize that it seems to be a problem with reading the data from the connection. All other operations are working fine, I can access the data directly, only `GetValues` fails.

I wrote a fast and simple test application which yields the same error, but also outputs the following statement after terminating:

```
Error in my_thread_global_end(): 1 threads didn't exit
```

I'm not sure if this is related or not, so sorry for the confusion.

I'm lost once again...has anyone seen something like this before?

**Edit:** Here's my test application:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace ODBCTest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            try {
                Console.WriteLine ("Creating connection...");
                using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection ("ConnStringHere")) {
                    conn.Open ();
                    Console.WriteLine ("Creating command...");
                    using (OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand ()) {
                        cmd.CommandText = "SimpleSelectHere;";

                        Console.WriteLine ("Creating reader...");
                        using (OdbcDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader ()) {
                            if (rdr != null && !rdr.IsClosed) {
                                while (rdr.Read ()) {
                                    object[] temp = new object[rdr.FieldCount];
                                    rdr.GetValues (temp);
                                }

                                Console.WriteLine ("Seems to work fine.");
                            } else {
                                Console.WriteLine ("Could not create reader!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine (ex.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine ();
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine (ex.InnerException.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine (ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine("No InnerException.");
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey ();
        }
    }
}
```

And it's output:

```
Creating connection...
Creating command...
Creating reader...

   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetData(Int32 i, SQL_C sqlctype, Int32 cb, Int32& cbActualOut)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.internalGetString(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i, TypeMap typemap)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
   at ODBCTest.MainClass.Main(String[] args)

No InnerException.
<At this point I hit a key>
Error in my_thread_global_end(): 1 threads didn't exit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll be damned! This is a [bug in the MDAC 2.7](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;319243), installing 2.8 (or the hotfix) fixes this.

And the thread-error message is a bug in [the used MySQL ODBC-Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-odbc-news-5-1-9.html).

Answer (score 0):

I also observed this problem in MDAC 2.6 SP2 while working with Sybase DB, installing version 2.8 SP1 helped in my case.